# Sqlserver Error on Inner join with overflow Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to run this simple query but I'm having this error:

[image]
[image]

```
Select  I.RecipeId,
   I.Name 
    from  Ingredient as I 
     inner  join 
      Recipe  as R
       on  
       I.RecipeId   = CAST( R.id AS nvarchar(MAX)) 
         where 
          I.RecipeId >= 241956 
          AND 
          I.RecipeId <= 242018
```

> The conversion of the varchar value '160088961736173116            ' overflowed an int column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fundamental problem in your data model.  In the`recipe` table, the `id` is `bigint`.  In the `ingredient` column, the type is `varchar(30)`.

Fix the data model!  The referring types should be the same type.  This is a very important principle when using relational databases.  The columns that represent relationships need to be compatible.

I would start with:

```
alter table ingredient alter column recipeId bigint;
```

If this doesn't work due to a conversion error, then you need to find the offending value.  You can try:

```
select *
from ingredient
where recipeId like '%[^0-9]%';
```

This should find the offending values.

Answer (score 3):

RecipeID is a literal value that's being compared against a hard-coded integer `241956`. This forces the motor to convert all values stored in `RecipeID` to an integer value. Since there's at least one value (`160088961736173116`) that exceeds the max value for an integer, it fails.

You can explicitly convert your hard-coded value to a `BIGINT` which can hold higher values, including `160088961736173116`. Try this out:

```
Select  
    I.RecipeId,
    I.Name 
from  
    Ingredient as I 
    inner  join Recipe as R on CONVERT(BIGINT, I.RecipeId) = R.id
where 
    I.RecipeId  BETWEEN CONVERT(BIGINT, 241956) AND CONVERT(BIGINT, 242018)
```

Comment: EzLo, Your query make no sense. You use `I.RecipeId = CAST(R.id AS nvarchar(MAX))`.  but `I.RecipeId` is INT and `R.id` is BIGINT, so why do you change `R.id` to nvarchar in order to compare it to int?!? After the CAST you compare string to number. You should convert both to the same type - in this case to the bigger type which is BIGINT

Comment: @Ronen, EzLo answer underpins what the issue is - RecipeId column is stored as varchar allowing it to store 160088961736173116. To resolve this. The column needs to be casted to bigint to allow comparison with Recipe tables Id (which is bigint).

Comment: For your information @MEdwin: EzLo edited his answer AFTER I wrote my comment! which is one of the main reason I hate stackoverflow interface. This type of actions made a comment irrelevant and lead to responses like your! Check the history of the answer's edits and you will see that EzLo first tried to convert the value to string and compare string to integer! This was copied from his answer: `I.RecipeId = CAST(R.id AS nvarchar(MAX))`

Comment: What is sad, is that your comment get votes while my that lead to fix the answer become irrelevant and seems like I wrote something wrong... there are reasons why I prefer to use MSDN forums (where I serve as Moderator) over stackoverflow, and this is one of these reasons :-(

Comment: @RonenAriely yes you are right, seems that I've edited the answer after your comment and probably the upvoter misunderstood your message. I'm sorry i didnt leave a comment with the edit, as I'm used to deleting these type of comments after edition.

Comment: Thanks EzLo. I highly appreciate your clarification. By the way, In my opinion a discussion forum should keep the history clearly documented as it was (not in hidden history edits list). It should present the discussion as a list of steps that led to the final answer. Therefore, it should be presented in hierarchical structure (tree structure), were each response is clearly related to the message it respond to (for example MSDN forums), and messages should not updated after they got responses. Please don't remove comments in the future, so at least there will be sense in related comments :-)

Comment: OH.... that is really unfair. I will watch out for this in future. My bad, I am still learning.